# import-module located on network share

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a module located on a network share the I wish to load during remote session to other servers on my network.

Here my commands:

```
enter-pssession remoteserver
import-module \\shareserver\sharefolder\SPModule.misc
```

Here is the error:

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'SPModule.misc' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (SPModule.misc:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Are modules not able to load from network shares or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Adding this as an answer to make it easier to find.)

You need to enable second-hop remoting with CredSSP.

[PowerShell 2.0 remoting guide: Part 12 – Using CredSSP for multi-hop authentication](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1230)

[CredSSP for second-hop remoting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/06/05/credssp-for-second-hop-remoting-part-i-domain-account.aspx)

[PowerShell Remoting and the “Double-Hop” Problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2009/06/25/9803001.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

By default, it looks for modules by name in whatever path(s) are listed in the PSModulePath environment variable. I know you can also provide an absolute path, but I've never tried a UNC.

That said, module filenames end in either .psm1, .psd1, or .dll - ".misc" isn't a valid module filename. From the help:

```
Specifies the names of the modules to import. Enter the name of the module or the name of a file in the module, such as a .psd1, .psm1, .dll, or ps1 file. File paths are optional. Wildcards are not permitted. You can also pipe module names and file names to Import-Module.

If you omit a path, Import-Module looks for the module in the paths saved in the PSModulePath environment variable ($env:PSModulePath).
```

Try renaming your module to .psm1 (if it is in fact a Script Module).

Comment: Thanks but this is not it.  This import-module statement works just fine when I am not remoting to another machine.  I am getting close by information found on this site: http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1230

Answer (score 0):

When a PS session is created and authenticates through Kerberos, the session doesn't support double hop. Therefore, the PS session can't authenticate by using network resources.

Resolution:
On the computer that is the target of the Enter-PSSession command, run this command:

```
> Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server
```

On the computer on which you run the Enter-PSSession command, run this command:

```
> Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer Servername
```

Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/af-za/help/4076842